# Providing internet access to my self hosted web api on an internal network. A security threat?

Tags: ajax, security, asp.net-web-api, forwarding

Firstly, I'm relatively new to Web API / CORS and security implementation.

This question is specifically with regards to security. The Web API houses extremely sensitive data and provides clients with the ability to execute transactions online.

The context :

- I have a Web API self hosted as a windows service with a fixed port.
- The Web API is sitting behind a firewall / DMZ on an internal network.
- The Web API (using CORS) only allows traffic from the external server.
- The external server hosts our web site using IIS.
- The Web API is making use of Token authentication (bound to client IP to avoid hi-jacking).
- Both the external website and internal Web API force the use of SSL.

The problem :

The web page makes ajax calls via javascript to the Web API. However, the Web API is not directly exposed to the internet.

- What would the security impact be on having the below setup?
- What sort of vulnerabilities would I be exposing my network too by doing so.
- Is there a better way of implementing such a setup!?

Eg

- User enters `https://test.mydomain.com` into the browser and is served a page.
- ajax call gets made to `https://test.mydomain.com/api/test/action`
- external server routes `https://test.mydomain.com/api` messages to internal server `https://myInternalWebAPI/api/test/action` which is not exposed to the public.

Comment: This is a great article (IMO) about securing public REST webservices: http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/designing-a-secure-rest-api-without-oauth-authentication/

Comment: @EkoostikMartin Thanks for this link, however, I'm already using 95% of these practices in my design. My question is really whether the network administrator would be comfortable forwarding the already protected ajax traffic to the internal webapi

Comment: You are actually going overboard (though this isn't a bad thing I guess). Web Servers in the DMZ need to communicate with application servers outside the DMZ, this is unavoidable outside of the most simple systems. This is normally not for a software architect to worry about, but the network/security admin. For example, not sure why you need HTTPS on internal server if you are using token based authentication based on IP address.

Comment: Outside of their existing "security" (port isolation, proxy, AD) the securing of the application falls on me, thus far they have not been very accomodating with allowing ports for services etc and extremely restrictive regarding access to their network.

The HTTPS follow through is merely to maintain that the traffic is secure from endpoint-to-endpoint.

The overboard manner of implementation is to ease (their minds with regards to) the installation of the product.

Comment: How exactly are you routing external `https://test.mydomain.com/api` to internal `https://myInternalWebAPI/api/test/action` ?

Comment: I'm not routing it at all yet! I want the network admin to route it. To be honest I'm not even sure how to route/forward the http message from the one server to the other :S? I thought a proxy might be a simple enough solution, though I have no idea how to implement a proxy.

Comment: Reverse proxy yes, but again this is a network engineer thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this requires a little bit of leg work, but it's implemented into a production environment so I thought I'd share the solution.

I created a WCF service and a WebAPI.

The primary WCF Service resides on the internal network and contains all the business logic, database connectivity.
The proxy WebAPI mimics the WCF service structure and is exposed to the public.

The proxy WebAPI is called from the client (javascript), the proxy WebAPI then calls the internal server hosting the WCF service and voila, victory.

Comment: Made it so easy. Am I trying to do the same as you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43002283/how-to-allow-internal-mvc-web-api-from-external-site-outside-the-network