# How to allow internal MVC Web Api from external site outside the network

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, cors

I have a MVC Web API (hosted in IIS) which is in the wwwroot folder and locally accessible within the network.I can execute api calls like this: `http://mylocalapi:133/api/Values/Get` and I get a result.

I have an external site which is `http://example.org` and I would like to execute the same `http://mylocalapi:133/api/Values/Get`.

Both the external facing site as well as the internal API site is hosted on the same server (but it can be different, for example a 3rd party vendor outside of the network)

I have CORS set up in my API like this:

`[EnableCors(origins: "http://example.org", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`

But I keep getting the following error:

`XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mylocalapi:133. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.org' is therefore not allowed access.`

So get around it, I created a virtual directory (`APICALLS`) in my external site and created a web.config file which will point to the local IIS site:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="http://mylocalapi:133" exactDestination="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

When I do that, I try to access the API like this: `http://example.org/APICALLS/api/Values/Get` but I get the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mylocalapi:133. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://example.org' is therefore not allowed access.
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I resolve the issue.

Comment: You re attempting to make a web request to your localhost from an external site, am i wrong? if it is, you can not.

Comment: @ibubi Even with the virtual directory?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access an internal-only site from JavaScript, as JavaScript runs client-side, on the end-user's machine, outside of your internal network. The only way to hit the API via JavaScript is to either 1) expose the API to the external network or 2) create a proxy within your external site.

The proxy would be basically an action or actions that offer external access, and then translate the calls to your internal API. At the simplest, you could have a single action that basically responds to something like:

```
https://foo.com/api?endpoint=/internal/api/endpoint/&someParam=foo
```

The action would then take this information in the query string and use that to make a request to your internal API via something like `HttpClient`. However, this approach pretty much exposes your whole internal API, so you might as well just move it outside at that point. The better approach would be to create specific endpoints (action methods) for specific internal API calls you need to make via JavaScript.

**UPDATE**

It's difficult to give you any real direction here without context. Let's say that there's an internal API endpoint that returns a list of widgets and you want to retrieve this list of widgets via AJAX. You would need something like:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> GetWidgets()
{
    // fetch widgets from internal API via HttpClient
    return Json(widgets, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then, your AJAX would call the URL for this action method on your website, which under the hood calls the internal API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Well the Javascript isn't hitting the API, or am I wrong? I have the virtual directory in IIS which points to the internal site. So technically the Javascript is only hitting the virtual directory on the server which tells it to access a local site. How do I achieve #1? I tried to copy the files/folders from the API folde and move it to a subfolder I created in my external site but I get a different error there.

Comment: Or better yet... how can I achieve this: `The better approach would be to create specific endpoints (action methods) for specific internal API calls you need to make via JavaScript.`? Thanks so much

Comment: What you're currently doing is attempting to *redirect* the requests as they come in. A redirect will cause a response to be sent with `Location` header. The client, then, is responsible for issuing a new request to that specified location, which it still can't do, because it's internal-only.

Comment: So the API files/folder will have to be on it's IIS site which is accessible from outside, like http://myapisite.org?

Comment: Not necessarily, but it would have to be exposed to the external network. *How* you achieve that is fairly inconsequential. The alternative is to proxy the requests, as shown above.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Maybe we can go to chat to discuss further?

Comment: @Si8 The reason for your error, origin, while the XMLHttpRequest is from the webpage hosted on "example.org" it is not the SERVER that makes the call, it is the javascript as Chris said. This means the origin is the client browser which is no "example.org"

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in your WebApiConfig class in in Register method

```
config.EnableCors();
```

Comment: I have it done already hence why I have the header in my API .cs file.